# QtDBus: expose two different interfaces on two different services

Tags: qt, qtdbus

I am trying to develop a stand-alone status notifier app to display "tray icons". KDE developed a dbus spec for this where apps can register a status notifier icon via dbus. The service that waits for the apps is `org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher`, the object path is `/StatusNotifierWatcher` and the interface used is `org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher`. Now that this is becoming the standard, FD.O has proposed that the dbus service to be used should be `org.freedesktop.StatusNotifierWatcher`. However, this is in the process of being adopted, and `org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher` is more commonly used one.

In my app, I would like to provide both these services. I can register the services quite easily. However, the problem is the interfaces. I would like to expose the `org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher` interface via the `org.kde.StatusNotifierWatcher` service and the freedesktop interface with `org.freedesktop.StatusNotifierWatcher`. Whatever I try, I end up with either both interfaces on both services or one interface on both services.

Since the code is quite lengthy, I have uploaded it to a repo: https://gitlab.com/marcusbritanicus/sni-test

TL;DR: How do I expose two different interfaces on two different services in a single app.